# Using ninja forms, how can I persist field values across pages?

Tags: forms, wordpress, ninja-forms

I have a form on the home page of quotedjobs.com that I would like to persist the field values of across pages.

For example: A user enters some values in fields, such as job title (textbox), job type (list) and job description (text field). Underneath that I ask users to register on the site, but they have the option to click a link to allow them to login if they are already members.

What I would like to be able to do, is to redirect users to another form that is a copy, but allows them to login instead of register, but keep hold of the values that they entered in the title, type and description form of the previous page so they aren't losing their work.

I have seen the `ninja_forms_processing` variable in the docs, but I'm not clear on how to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR - You can't.

As it was slim pickings here, I sent an email over to support. Got this response:

Hello,

At this time this use case is not possible in Ninja Forms. The plugin is currently unable to transfer data from field to field or between forms.
I’m sorry that we do not have a better solution for you at this time.

Thank you,